# The designer could not be shown for this file because none of the classes within it can be designed. Visual C#

Tags: c#

Trying to create a new windows form application and I keep getting this problem

at

> System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.EnsureDocument(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   manager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager
>   serializationManager) at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32
>   fReload)

Any ideas on what the problem could be?

Comment: Tried repairing the VS install?

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario I needed to extend a UserControl by adding a couple of custom methods.  To do this I created a class that inherited UserControl, and my new user controls that required the extended functionality would inherit the extended control.

Not sure what the cause is, but if my compile options were set to x64 I had the same issue you are reporting.  Changing this to AnyCPU fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks Brian! I changed it from x64 to "Any CPU" & rebuilt the solution. When I opened the usercontrol in the designer, I actually got an error (I wasn't before). I fixed the error, and now the designer works.  Looks like when target is x64 & the designer errors, the error message is suppressed.  Thanks again.